# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User as BaseUser

CHOICE_GENDER = ((1, 'Male'), (2, 'Female'))


class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return ', '.join([self.city, self.state])


class Users(BaseUser):
    user = models.OneToOneField(BaseUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = models.DateField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('user',)
```

forms.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from .models import Users, Location, CHOICE_GENDER


class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    country = forms.CharField(max_length=25)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ('city', 'country',)


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=75)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER)
    birth = forms.DateField()
    location = LocationForm()

    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'gender', 'birth', 'location')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        user.birth = self.cleaned_data['birth']
        user.location = self.cleaned_data['location']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.forms import formset_factory
from . import forms


def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        loc_form = forms.LocationForm(request.POST)
        if loc_form.is_valid():
            loc = loc_form.save()
            RegistrationFormSet = formset_factory(forms.RegistrationForm)
            formset = RegistrationFormSet(request.POST, instance=loc)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('./')
            # else:
                # how to make to render the POST data to the template page and fill all fields?
    return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

I'm getting the error from the title at at `formset = RegistrationFormSet(request.POST, instance=loc)`. I'm trying to create a valid view which will invoke call to another form before saving to the main one, so that's why I'm using FormSet, but I can't manage to make it work. Can someone help me about that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

RegistrationFormSet is created by a call to formset_factory, so it knows nothing about instances. I think you mean to use [`inlineformset_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets), which does support them.

Comment: It requires parameter "model" to be specified, so what to put there? I've tried to change that line to `RegistrationFormSet = inlineformset_factory(forms.RegistrationForm, model=Users)` but it doesn't work, it throws this error: `'ModelFormOptions' object has no attribute 'get_parent_list'`. Thanks for the help!